# Converting bitstring to string in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm just new to Elixir.

After generating a hmac hash, I got a `bitstring`:

```
:crypto.hmac(:sha512, secret, data)
Sign: <<104, 155, 224, 193, 121, 129, 237, 103, 233, 236, 161, 130...>>
```

Now, I have to convert it to `String`, but don't know how exactly.

Any Elixir/erlang module to do this directly?

Comment: Instead of editing in your answer, please post it as an answer to your question and accept it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok @AMACB, I'll do this way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Make sure to accept it too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, I didn't see that you originally want to use the output of the bitstring with the [String Module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/String.html). You already can! You can see this by trying to pipe your output into `String.length` and getting a successful return value.

This [getting started guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html) does a good job of walking through the basics. Specifically how "A string is a UTF-8 encoded binary".

What do you want to be able to do with the output?

If you you instead want to be able to pass the hash through URL for an auth system or something like that, I left the original answer.

---

You can use the [Base Module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Base.html) to achieve that.

For example you could pipe the output like

`:crypto.hmac(:sha512, secret, data) |> Base.encode64`

If you need it to be filename or url safe there is an alternative `url_encode64` function.

Comment: Thanks @the-brofessor. I'll post it to an API authenticating my access.
Just used `Base.encode16`

`Base.encode16(:crypto.hmac(:sha512, secret, postdata), case: :lower)`